# How to switch account packages in Meteor

Tags: meteor, package, accounts

right now I have the Meteor accounts-password and joshowens:accounts-entry packages installed. My app is currently using the joshowens:accounts-entry, but is not compatible with Meteor 1.2 so I want to switch the accounts system back to the standard Meteor accounts-password package. Does anyone know how to do this? Do I just uninstall joshowens:accounts-entry and it'll default to Meteor accounts-password?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

**Hi!**

To remove a package, we use:

```
$ meteor remove <package_name>
```

So, to remove `joshowens:accounts-entry`:

```
$ meteor remove joshowens:accounts-entry
```

For more, refer the [relevant docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/packages).

**Hope this helps.**